# Best way to replace sealant where concrete driveway meets foundation?

Tags: concrete, foundation, outdoor, caulking, sealant

We purchased our house in 2022, it had been previously used as a rental. There are plenty of other examples of your typical "Landlord's Special" around the house — over-caulking in the bathroom, cheap materials, lousy paint jobs, and so forth. I'm able to handle most of these, even as a novice DIY'er, but one thing that's been bugging me is outside the house where our concrete driveway meets the side of the house. There appears to be some sort of poorly-applied (or very aged) sealant at the junction. Feels like rock to the touch, not sure if it's caulking or some sort of quick-dry concrete.

Anyone have any idea what's going on here? Given the fact that it's obviously degrading, I'm eager to remove and replace this before we end up with any damage, but I want to make sure I have the right information first. I've seen lots of folks recommend cleaning out the old stuff, inserting backer rod, then caulking to seal the junction, but I've also seen a lot of people saying *not* to use caulk and to take a masonry approach instead.

I'm eager to learn. What am I looking at here?

[image: Sealant (?) where concrete driveway meets foundation]

Comment: Does your area freeze, ever? If so, the driveway will move relative to the house, and a method that accommodates that annual movement will be needed. Mind you, the present situation (sealant ripped open as if the driveway sunk) looks like the base was not sufficiently compacted and the driveway settled, which is a different sort of movement, less likely to repeat, if that's completed settling to its final level. Also - does water pool here, or flow away from the house, still?

Comment: Plenty of freezing, we live in southwest Michigan. That's very useful to know, we've also noticed a few other areas of the driveway that have raised a bit as well. Nothing too dramatic but we'll watch out. Haven't taken a close look at water pooling yet, but we're due for some rain this week so I'll keep an eye on that. Thanks for the thoughtful response!